# How to replace space with new line

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP variable which contains numbers separated by a space. I want to replace each space with a new line and then want to put those numbers into a list or HTML table.

Here's an example string:

```php
$numbers = "9844786187 9844786187 9864097002 9864097002 9590951428 9590951428 9839014611 9839014611 9039771174 9039771174";
```

These numbers are dynamic and there could be more or less numbers.

How can I achieve my output?

Comment: You ask bad questions. [You should read this before you post your next one.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: How about using str_replace()? http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (*think I*) clarified your question and believe you're attempting to take a list of numbers in a string, separated by spaces, and output it in different ways (eg, list or table). The approach you asked us to use doesn't sound like the best for this. Instead, I would suggest [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```php
$numbers = "9844786187 9844786187 9864097002 9864097002 9590951428 9590951428 9839014611 9839014611 9039771174 9039771174";
$number_array = explode(" ", $numbers);

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($number_array as $number){
 echo "\t<li>$number</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n"
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>9844786187</li>
    <li>9844786187</li>
    <li>9864097002</li>
    <li>9864097002</li>
    <li>9590951428</li>
    <li>9590951428</li>
    <li>9839014611</li>
    <li>9839014611</li>
    <li>9039771174</li>
    <li>9039771174</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, you can use str_replace():

```
$numbers = str_replace(' ', '\n', $numbers);
```

preg_replace is a "super" str_replace(), usign regex, you can use it the same way

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/ /', '\n', $numbers);
```

Those `/` are delimiters. In your case, regex are useless. You should use str_replace.

And as Daryll Gill suggested, using :

```
$numbers = str_replace(' ', '<br>', $numbers);
```

Will give better result for web printing. You can use `nl2br()` function on numbers on printing to get the same result with the first replacing proposal

Comment: If printing to a web page. Would it not be best to replace space with <br>

Comment: @DarylGill Good idea. I'll add this solution to.